# how to find bad data causing ORA-01722

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, ora-01722

I'm using ojdbc8 to run a straight-forward query that throws `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number` for certain results.

This happens in SQL Developer and via java API (name is a varchar here):

```
Statement sel = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = sel.executeQuery("select * from t1 order by name");
while(rs.next())
```

Through debugging, I've isolated several rows that cause the error but when I select against those rows only (rather than select *), I don't experience the error, which leads me to believe that this may some kind of driver/performance issue?

I've also tried finding bad data with code I found here on SO but it returns without error (`PL/SQL procedure successfully completed`):

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
   exc EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(exc, -1722);
   l_message VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
   'select * from t1 order by name';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN exc THEN
      l_message := regexp_replace(sqlerrm, '^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{5}: "([^"]+)".*$', '\1');

      dbms_output.put_line ( 'bad data '''||l_message||'''');
      dbms_output.put_line ( 'exception: sqlcode='||SQLCODE||', sqlerrm='''||sqlerrm||'''');

   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: The most likely thing is that you are using a tool that fetches only n rows first. Within these rows everything was fine. Now you changed the order and the first n rows include a condition that fails (e.g. `where my_string_that_also_contains_numbers = 5`, where the original query coincidentally first grabbed strings that contained numbers and now you are getting non-numeric values that fail on conversion)..

Comment: You got to show us what's there in `ORDER BY` not just adding `this,that`

Comment: Also present us with the data types of the columns you are ordering on.

Comment: show you real sql code  .. you actual code have not sense

Comment: Is your `t2.status` column of type `number` or `varchar2`? I'm guessing you have non-numeric data in it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It is bad data (Thorsten).